# Custom webpart doesn't show for external users

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

So I just created a custom webpart and added it to my communication site. After enable all the stuff for external users. The users can see the site just fine except for the custom webpart, it showed the error below. I would appreciate any help.

````
Failed to load component "90421966-2fcc-440f-a39a-356b963f443f" (SpFxCrudWebPart). Original error: Failed to load path dependency "SpFxCrudWebPartStrings" from component "90421966-2fcc-440f-a39a-356b963f443f" (SpFxCrudWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/90421966-2fcc-440f-a39a-356b963f443f_0.0.1/SpFxCrudWebPartStrings
    Unable to load script https://xdq4y.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/9f43e5bf-e797-4272-a779-92df96ac8605/SpFxCrudWebPartStrings_en-us.js

INNERERROR:
Failed to load path dependency "SpFxCrudWebPartStrings" from component "90421966-2fcc-440f-a39a-356b963f443f" (SpFxCrudWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/90421966-2fcc-440f-a39a-356b963f443f_0.0.1/SpFxCrudWebPartStrings
    Unable to load script https://xdq4y.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/9f43e5bf-e797-4272-a779-92df96ac8605/SpFxCrudWebPartStrings_en-us.js
CALLSTACK:
Error
    at t [as constructor] (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_fr-fr_43c1a4b11ea7bfb2549706733ebaa7f4.js:70:214984)
    at new t (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_fr-fr_43c1a4b11ea7bfb2549706733ebaa7f4.js:70:781395)
    at e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_fr-fr_43c1a4b11ea7bfb2549706733ebaa7f4.js:70:818737)
    at e.buildLoadComponentError (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_fr-fr_43c1a4b11ea7bfb2549706733ebaa7f4.js:70:814828)
    at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.systemjs-component-loader_fr-fr_5659168cd2dbf133c865.js:1:6036```
````

Comment: Is this communication site used in private/enterprise network or opened/home network?

Comment: Hi I created it at home so I guess opened/home network @AntonioLeonardo

Comment: At this article have a complete explanation about this error: [SPFx | Failed to load component](https://www.koskila.net/failed-to-load-component-original-error-failed-to-load-path-dependency-contosospfxwebpartlocalization-from-component-guid-contosospfxwebpart/). Hope this can help you